# Apply facebox to links displayed using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebox

I have a small problem. So I have this page that loads dynamic content using jQuery Ajax after the page is done loading. On the top of the page is a link called "Add News". When you click on that Link, a facebox pops open. This link is static and is only displayed once on the top of the page. Its labeled:

```
<a href="linktopage" rel='facebox[.xhr]'>Add News</a>
```

The dynamic page (loaded from Ajax) lists all the existing news in the DB. They are labeled:

```
<a href="linktonews?id=1" rel='facebox[.xhr]'>News 1</a>
<a href="linktonews?id=2" rel='facebox[.xhr]'>News 2</a>
<a href="linktonews?id=3" rel='facebox[.xhr]'>News 3</a>
```

and so on... Clicking one of the news items, open a facebox where you can view/edit the news.

Every time a new news item is added, the dynamic content reloads without refreshing the page.

The definition of facebox is instantiated using `$('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();` when the main index page is loaded.

Now my problem is that this `$('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();` does not apply to the news content loaded using ajax. So clicking on those links does not open a facebox. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with facebox, but you should check to see if there's a callback for it completes loading the ajax content. Instantiate facebox again in that callback.

Comment: How are you AJAX loading the content? Using `.load`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem so I started looking at the pull requests in GitHub and found:

https://github.com/dator/facebox/commit/5ce6a75927d81b9fff1eeff9b933f0ad93f12801

by Dator (props to him! :D)

As it seems that the pull request isn't merged yet I just changed that line in my facebox.js and it works great :D

Hope this helps :)